# Creating a DataFrame by aggregating by each column

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

I have a `DataFrame`, where all columns are in `binary` form, i.e; taking either `0` or `1` as value as shown below.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'qualified_exam':[1,1,0,0,1,1],'gender_M':[1,0,1,0,1,1],'employed':[1,0,0,1,1,1],'married':[0,1,0,1,1,0]})
print(df)
      qualified_exam  gender_M  employed  married
   0               1         1         1        0
   1               1         0         0        1
   2               0         1         0        0
   3               0         0         1        1
   4               1         1         1        1
   5               1         1         1        0
```

I want to create a `DataFrame` where I want to measure `sum/mean` of column `qualified _exam` by `grouping by` all the remaining 3 columns individually - `gender_M`, `employed`, `married`.

Final DataFrame should look something like this -

```
            sum_0   sum_1    mean_0    mean_1
gender_M        1       3      0.50      0.75
employed        1       3      0.50      0.75
 married        2       2      0.66      0.66
```

I tried it by doing `groupby()` and `agg()` for each of the 3 columns individually, and then appending the result one by one. This is too cumbersome. I am sure there is a better way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with aggregate `sum` with `mean`, reshape by [`DataFrame.unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and last flatten `MultiIndex in columns`:

```
df1 = (df.melt('qualified_exam')
         .groupby(['variable', 'value'])['qualified_exam']
         .agg(['sum','mean'])
         .unstack()

         )
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
print (df1)
          sum_0  sum_1    mean_0    mean_1
variable                                  
employed      1      3  0.500000  0.750000
gender_M      1      3  0.500000  0.750000
married       2      2  0.666667  0.666667
```

Or use [`DataFrame.pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot_table.html):

```
df1 = (df.melt('qualified_exam')
         .pivot_table(index='variable', 
                      columns='value', 
                      values='qualified_exam', 
                      aggfunc=('sum','mean')))
df1.columns = df1.columns.map(lambda x: f'{x[0]}_{x[1]}')
print (df1)
            mean_0    mean_1  sum_0  sum_1
variable                                  
employed  0.500000  0.750000    1.0    3.0
gender_M  0.500000  0.750000    1.0    3.0
married   0.666667  0.666667    2.0    2.0
```

Comment: Hallo, Many thanks for answer. This code fails when any column has only 0s or 1s. For eg; Just change 'gender_M':[0,0,0,0,0,0] and the result wll be 0,0,0,0.

Comment: Yes, I at the moment I need these 4 columns - ´sum_0, sum_1, mean_0, mean_1´. But, I may extend it to include 'count' as well.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand - 'Is possible specify 0,1 ? '.

Comment: @Let me do a detailed check to be sure that the program is behaving as expected. I'll be right back.

Comment: Hi Jazreal, I took a close look. Actually, the result is not correct. Have a look at the top, the result is `married       1      2     0.5    0.50`, where as expected one was `married        2       2      0.66      0.66`.

Comment: For `married` there are 3 `0s` and 3 `1s`. Each of these 2 groups have 2 `qualified_exam` = `1`. So, the sum is `2 2` and average is `2/3=0.66` for both of them.

Comment: Well, you are looking at this problem the other way around, I think.

Comment: Yes, I notice that. I was expecting just the opposite, where we `groupby` each of the 3 columns.

Comment: @cph_sto - Answer was edited, swapped columns for values and column ;)

Comment: @cph_sto - You can check [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65124597/revisions)

Comment: Dear Jezreal. You are the king of SO. It works perfectly. I have checked it on my internal dataset as well with million of rows.

Comment: @cph_sto - I think not necessary ;) But thank you.

Comment: Well, that's the least I could do :)